# swift split view navigation in master

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a new split view and in the interface builder I have added 2 more table views to the master view, and updated the segues like so:

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P3YD.png)

all works as expected, except for the fact that on the iphone plus, when I navigate to the second table view controller in portrait mode, and I go to landscape, the split screen shows in master my first table and in the details the second table.

[splitscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibvzt.png)

If I go to landscape on the first table, in the master I have the first table, and in the detail is the detail as it should and if I navigate in the master, the navigation happens in the master as it should

How do I get it to always show the detail view controller in the detail of the split view?

Comment: If you look into `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`, you can supply implementations for `primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController:` and `primaryViewControllerForExpandingSplitViewController:`, which allow you to specify which view controller is to be set as primary, during the transitions from regular-width to compact-width (and visa-versa).

Comment: If the root view of your app is a `UISplitViewController`, then the App Delegate would be a good candidate to be the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for was actually `separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController` but your comment got me there :D

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the answer is for swift 3.0

```
// This is called every time the splitview is shown, and it decides what to show in the detail
// Since we need the details to always show the detail, we should always return the detail
// but if we return the detail when we already are on detail it will make the splitview show
// the detail in both views; so we try to detect when we are on detail
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryFrom primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var is_detail = false

    // because we have to nav controllers linked to the split view, the primary will always be nav
    if let nav = primaryViewController as? UINavigationController {
        // if the top controller of primary is yet another nav controller, this means we navigated to the detail (follow the arrow, and count the nav controllers :D)
        if let nav2 = nav.topViewController as? UINavigationController {
            // now just to be thourough, we check to see if there is a DetailViewController
            if nav2.topViewController is DetailViewController {
                is_detail = true
            }
        }
    }

    // if the primary is actually a detail, we return nil, and let splitview to do it's job
    if is_detail {
        // splitview will show in the master the previous view controller & in detail the current view controller
        return nil
    } else {
        // splitview will keep the current view controller in master, and add this controller in detail
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailView")
    }
}
```